# ASP.NET Core MVC : ModelState error message - localization not working

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, resources, globalization

en-US:

[image]

zh-CN:

[image]

Why are `[Display(Name = "LoginUserName")]` and other data annotations not working?

This is my localization config

[image]

What could be the fix for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following two ways:

**1. Use the old way of localizing data annotations:**

```
[Display(Name = nameof(MyResources.LoginUserName), 
         ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
```

**2. [DataAnnotation localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#dataannotations-localization) can be configured in the startup file(Put in Program.cs in .NET 6):**

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(o=>o.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o=> {
        var type = typeof(ViewResource);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        var factory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
        var localizer = factory.Create("ViewResource", assemblyName.Name);
        o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (t, f) => localizer;
    });
```

Here is a [work demo](https://github.com/LazZiya/MyTrips), you can refer to it.

Hope this can help you.